# Making a symlink to a python script in cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, symlink

I have a python script `D:/programs/Python programs/alarm.py` which I want to make a symlink to in `D:/cygwin/usr/local/bin`. I used this command:

```
ln -s 'D:/programs/Python programs/alarm.py' 'D:/cygwin/usr/local/bin/alarm'
```

However, when I do `./alarm` from the directory where the symlink is stored, I get this error saying that python failed to open (path to symbolic link).

```
D:\Python\Python38-32\python.exe: can't open file '/usr/local/bin/alarm': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I don't understand. According to my understanding, this should have happened: the symbolic link gets resolved to `'D:/programs/Python programs/alarm.py'`, and so the command becomes just that. I don't see how python would try to open the symlink file.

When I try the same command but this time with the -r option to make it relative like so:

```
ln -sr 'D:/programs/Python programs/alarm.py' 'D:/cygwin/usr/local/bin/alarm'
```

I get this error instead:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/alarm: No such file or directory
```

When I run the `file` command on my sym link, I get this output:

```
alarm: broken symbolic link to ../../../../programs/Python programs/alarm.py
```

Why is it broken? Is it something to do with cygwin? Someone please explain. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are using a NOT Cygwin Python with a Cygwin "ln". The cygwin links are not understood from pure Windows program

Comment: @matzeri - but isn't the substitution of the symlink supposed to be performed before the execution of the `python` command?

Comment: Before ? The substition is done at calling time by the cygwin1.dll library. If you are using a NOT cygwin python, the substitution is never performed.